# Get frame height without navigation bar height and tab bar height in deeper view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a ViewController (B) which is handled by a PageViewController which is inside another ViewController (A) and open it modal. I have centered the ViewController (B) exactly in the middle of the screen. This works fine.

But when I push the ViewController (A) from a NavigationController the frame of ViewController (B) is to big and extends below the NavigationBar and the TabBar. But I want it centered between the NavigationBar and the TabBar.

I know how I can get the height of the navbar and the tabbar so I could resize ViewController (B):

```
var topBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
var bottomBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height
```

But this does not work deep down in the vier hierarchy in ViewController (B). self.navigationController and self.tabBarController are nil. So how can I get the height of the navbar and tabbar deeper down in the view hierarchy? Or do I just have to pass it down from one ViewController to another till I reach ViewController (B)? Or is there another more obvious way to center the view? Thanks.

(I have tried to post screenshots for better understanding but I miss the needed reputation points to post images, sorry)

Comment: Try `yourview.bounds` after viewDidAppear.

Comment: The bounds don't give me the topLayoutGuide and/or the bottonLayoutGuide

Comment: If you have opened the view controller modally it's not a child of the controller with the Tab Bar hence self.tabBarController is nil. It sits above it in the navigation stack. You'll have to pass that info through, e.g in prepare(for segue:). If you've opened modally then why do you want the user to think they can click on the tab buttons (which they probably can't)? Maybe you don't mean to open modally.

Answer (score 39):

Use this :

```
let height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height +
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
```

this support portrait and landscape state.

Swift 5

```
let height = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height +
      self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
```

Comment: In this situation navigationController == nil

Comment: Updated:
`UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height`

Comment: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height is nil for me.

Comment: May you aren't using navigationController in your controller.

Comment: That would work ONLY if you have a `UINavigationController`. The OP said his `UIViewController` is presented modally and it's not part of a `UINavigationController` stack, hence this code would crash for him, since 1 - force unwrapping `navigationController` and 2 - he doesn't have a one in his case

Answer (score 8):

For UITabBar, this code work :

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height
```

Comment: In this situation the tabBarController == nil

Answer (score 2):

**For  *Swift 3***

```
navBarHeight = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.intrinsicContentSize.height)! 
+ UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Comment: In this situation navigationController == nil

Answer (score 1):

As for **iOS 13**, since the `statusBarFrame` property of a UIApplication object was **deprecated**, one can use:

```swift
let statusBarHeight =  navigationController?.view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0

let navigationBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
```

---

Now, it may seem that doesn't help you @OP since your navigationController is nil, but you could try to use `view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height` for the statusBar height and figure out a way to find the navBar height as well? Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

iOS 13 solution:

```swift
extension UIViewController {

    /**
     *  Height of status bar + navigation bar (if navigation bar exist)
     */

    var topbarHeight: CGFloat {

        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first

        return (window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0) +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

To call it you can just use: `self.topbarHeight` in `viewController`

Answer (score -20):

Navigation bar height status bar height and tab bar height is always constant :

1. Navigation bar - 44pts
2. Status bar - 20pts
3. Tab bar - 49pts.

You can directly subtract these constants from view height:
self.view.frame.size.height- (44+20+49)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the view sometimes modal and sometimes pushed from a NavigationController so I need at least this to know during runtime.

Comment: This is also wrong. The status bar is 40 pts during a phone call.

Comment: @DylanGattey This is not wrong , please read the question first , there is no reference to phone call.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh If the user is in a phone call and is trying to use the app, the status bar is actually 40pts high, throwing off these calculations. So this answer is wrong in that situation. Your answer is not valid for all situations.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh Also, you can never know what Apple decides to change with the next versions of iOS, even 1px difference would break this.

Comment: This answer is really poor advice. You should rarely rely on magic numbers in general programming, and almost never  in UI programming. Apple frequently changes the size of UI elements. Just look at iOS 11, with major changes to title elements.  If you don't have direct access to the element info, then set up an Auto Layout constraint to that element, and use the values from the constraint for your calculations.